# No architectures to compile for (only_active_arch = yes, active arch = x86_64, valid_archs= i386

Tags: ios7.1, xcode5.1

I'm using `XCODE 5.1` and `IOS 7.1` for my project and when I compile it for `Iphone-simulator 64bit`, `Xcode` generates this error:

```
No architectures to compile for (only_active_arch = yes, active arch = x86_64, valid_archs= i386
```

I have already read others topics and I tried the solutions but I haven't resolved my problem.
I post my image settings:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't just fix valid_archs so that it includes x86_64 ?

Comment: Because I tried to change setting in Build Active Architecture Only to NO, but Xcode generates others errors.

Comment: What happens if you create a new project and add your files to it?

Comment: Why would I have to create another project and add my files to it? Is there a possibility to add a setting in architectures?

Answer (score 0):

If it helps I just added x86_64 to the valid architectures list and the message went away. (Although there are other issues in the code) 
The older projects are targeted to the old MAC processors - pre intel, if you dont add i386/x86_64 to the list it can't produce code that will run in the simulator.